# Need Help Adding Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

What I need right now is some step-by-step guidance on setting up a new test device. Just got a new iPad Air and need to set it up to test with. I've done all the registration setup in the Apple dev console, and am told there's a way of getting XCode to automatically do the rest, but I get lost there. Or maybe there's a better way, I don't know.

I believe my next moves involve the Provisioning Profile settings in my Project Build Settings area, to better allow XCode to auto-update the new device. If I could get a hand on what to do from here, I'd appreciate it.

I've attached a screen shot of that area to show the current settings.

[image: XCode Build Settings]

Comment: Firstly you should try googling. Secondly you need to add devices to developer.apple.com and add them to the profile in question then refresh :)

Comment: Have a read through this document called App Distribution Guide by Apple [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how manual generation works. I usually goes for that one, sometimes Xcode bugs with automatic generation (creating a tons of them, especially when you use more complex setup including team working with different repos or/and Xcode server)

1/ Add device UDID on your developer console (developer.apple.com / iOS dev center)

2/ Go to provisioning profile section edit your provisioning profile (or create one if you do not have one, you might have to create a certificat first if you do not have one, but everything is well explained in that section). Select devices that you registered

3/ Download your newly (re)generated profile. Double click on it to open it with Xcode

4/ On Xcode > Preferences, find out your developer account and refresh all provisioning profiles (There is a refresh button)

5/ Go to your project settings under provisioning profiles, select your profile. (When you regenerate profil, the previous one will be displayed there only by its serial number as he disappeared from disk)

Comment: Hey, Ganzolo;Thanks so much for the help. It worked! I took it slow, step by step, and in the end, my app ran on my new iPad. I had to make one adjustment, though, which I'd like to ask you about.

Comment: Thanks, Gonzolo. It worked!
`br`
When I first tried to run the app, though, the build failed, and I noticed that the previous profiles in the Code Signing > Provisioning Profile area had been replaced with ones showing a long serial number, like this:
55cf0e72-78f7-4e3e-8173-75bec322205e
and
163f16f5-5103-4a75-a1fc-f94ade18837c

When I went in and reset them back to the ones that had been showing before (see my original post image), which had been refreshed, the build was successful and the app came up on my iPad.

What happened there and what can I learn from that?

Thanks again!

Comment: It's just that you replaced the provisionning profile file. So xcode could not find it anymore on the disk (previous one). That's why he displayed the provisionning profile ID.